# Android Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am creating an app in which the players enter their names into edit texts. This information is retrieved and sent to a second activity through extras. Whenever I run this, I get a Resources$NotFoundException. I am nut sure if this is from my code or from my resources folder.

Here is my code (UPDATED WITHOUT TOAST STATEMENTS)

```
private void getNames(int number){      

    Intent intent = new Intent(Setup.this, Test.class);
    intent.putExtra("numberofplayers", number);

    try {

    if(!player1.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p1 = player1.getText().toString();
    else
        p1= "Player 1";
    if(!player2.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p2 = player2.getText().toString();
    else
        p2= "Player 2";
    if(!player3.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p3 = player3.getText().toString();
    else
        p3= "Player 3";
    if(!player4.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p4 = player4.getText().toString();
    else
        p5= "Player 5";
    if(!player6.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p6 = player6.getText().toString();
    else
        p6= "Player 6";
    if(!player7.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p7 = player7.getText().toString();
    else
        p7= "Player 7";
    if(!player8.getText().toString().contentEquals(""))
        p8 = player8.getText().toString();
    else
        p8= "Player 8";

    switch (number) {
    case 2:
        String[] a = {p1,p2};
        names=a;
        break;
    case 3:
        String[] b = {p1,p2,p3};
        names=b;
        break;
    case 4:
        String[] c = {p1,p2,p3,p4};
        names=c;
        break;
    case 5:
        String[] d= {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5};
        names=d;
        break;
    case 6:
        String[] e = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6};
        names=e;
        break;
    case 7:
        String[] f = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7};
        names=f;
        break;
    case 8:
        String[] g = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8};
        names=g;
        break;
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Setup.class Error:", e.getMessage());
    }
    //Toast.makeText(this, number + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //for(int q =0;q<names.length;q++)
    //  Toast.makeText(this, names[q], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    intent.putExtra("namearray", names);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the code for the receiving activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle ext = getIntent().getExtras();
    int i= ext.getInt("numberofplayers");
    String[] names = ext.getStringArray("namearray");

    Toast.makeText(this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    for(int q =0;q<names.length;q++)
        Toast.makeText(this, names[q], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And here is the logcat error (UPDATED LOGCAT REPORT):

```
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.brightdesign.truthordare/com.brightdesign.truthordare.Test}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:260)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at com.brightdesign.truthordare.Test.onCreate(Test.java:16)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-06 21:21:07.267: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: the reason for this error is ridiculous.. at least android should give proper reasonable error message. i wasted 2-3 hours on this error, i should have visit here early :(

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is your first Toast call:

```
Toast.makeText(this, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here, the second argument is an integer (`number`), so it thinks that is a string ID. Try replacing `number` with `number+""`.

Comment: A better way would be using `String.valueOf(number)`.

Comment: Ok... thanks, that was an error I didn't catch, but I only put the Toast statements in to see if the problem occured before or after the toast statement. When I remove the Toast statements, the app force closes. Any advice?

Comment: Please correct/remove that Toast line and post the new LogCat output so we can see where the force close error is.

Comment: @Drew - Again, your Toast call is `Toast.makeText(this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. As `i` is an integer, you need to convert it to a String using either Arhimed's or my solution above.

Comment: @Arhimed comment solved my problem. The problem was a text view "setText" with a int parameter instead of a String/Char sequence. Used "String.valueOf" and that's it. Thank you guys.

Comment: upvote for explanation.... if there wasn't the explanation... would have never tried this solution...